# Copy all folders to a new location except those containing invalid characters

Tags: bash

The aim is to create a Bash script that copies all folders and files within a folder to a new location.

The folder name from where the copying should take place should always match the following format:

`37ee0500-52c0-4a18-861e-0084EF05FB`

Folders are located in: `/user/members/local/` and should be copied to: `/user/members/clean/`.

The following scripts have been created, but none of these accomplish the aim.

**Script one:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;

if [[ "$1" =~ [^0-9A-Za-z]+ ]] ; then
echo "string $1 has characters which are not alphanumeric"
else
echo "string $1 has alphabets which are only alpha numeric"
fi
```

*Output:*

```
./test: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
./test: line 5: syntax error near `=~'
./test: line 5: `if [[ "$1" =~ [^0-9A-Za-z]+ ]] ; then'
```

**Script two**

```
if grep '^[-0-9a-zA-Z]*$' <<<$1 ;
  then echo ok;
    else echo ko;
    fi
```

*Output:*

`./test 37ee0500-52c0-4a18-861e-0084EF05FB` returns `ok` and `./test 37ee0500-5@c0-4#18-861e-00-0P{9F05FB` fails as expected.

**Update:**
This is working;

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW="/user/members/local";
OLD="/user/members/clean";

mv $NEW $OLD;
mkdir $NEW;

cd $OLD;

for f in *; do 

if grep '^[-_.0-9a-zA-Z]*$' <<< "$f" ; 
  then echo $f OK; cp -ar $f $NEW/$f;
     else echo $f Failed;              
fi

done
```

Comment: Can you explain what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: @viridis original post updated with example.

Comment: All files and folders match the same format, i.e. `37ee0500-52c0-4a18-861e-0084EF05FB`?

Comment: What version of Bash? Those error messages look like a very old version of Bash, such as 2.05b which didn't have `=~`. Regex matching first appeared in Bash 3 around 2004. Also, in your Bash version, the regex is unanchored so it wouldn't work as you intend. Regexes should be put into variables by habit since some patterns can't be included directly (e.g. those with whitespace). `pattern='^[^0-9A-Za-z]+$'; if [[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Linux system with GNU utilities (as opposed to BusyBox or something else), you can do this very efficiently with `find` and `cp`:

```
find /src -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9A-Za-z-]+$' -exec cp -r -t /dst {} +
```

This finds all directories at the top level of `/src` that contain only alphanumeric characters or hyphens, then passes all of them off to `cp` to recursively copy them into `/dst`. The `-t` option to `cp` lets you specify the "target directory" first, so all remaining arguments can be the items you want to copy. This allows you to use find's `{} +` construct, which causes it to pass as many of them as possible to a single `cp` invocation (similar to `xargs`). This way, if you have a ton of directories to copy, you aren't invoking `cp` once for each one.